# How to implement the correct uinavigationbar back button functionality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to go back to the previous view controller when i click on the cancel button of my search display controller i used the code :

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController: [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

but it gives me the following error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'search contents
>   navigation controller must not change between -setActive:YES and
>   -setActive:NO'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

will take you back to the previous view controller that was stacked in this navigation controller. that should do it..

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it assuming you just want to go back one VC in the nav stack.

Comment: it's hard to tell from what you described why the error occurs. i guess you are doing something to the navigation bar which causes this error. From the UINavigationBar documentation regarding the delegate property: "If the navigation bar was created by a navigation controller and is being managed by that object, you must not change the value of this property. Navigation controllers act as the delegate for any navigation bars they create." –

Answer (score 2):

My Problem was the searchdisplay controller cannot setActive by the uinavigator so i solve my problem by add the following code :

[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

the Error  was :

*** Assertion failure in -[UISearchDisplayController setActive:animated:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UISearchDisplayController.m:617
2012-05-13 19:07:44.696 MyApp[3648:11903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'search contents navigation controller must not change between -setActive:YES and -setActive:NO'

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found a solution.

The trick is not to give `searchDisplayController` to call `-setActive:animated:` anywhere but in `-viewWillDisappear`.
So you should make your view controller a delegate of the `searchBar` (to catch taps on "cancel" button) and lay a hidden button on background when `searchDisplayController` did become active (to catch taps on empty screen space).

In your view controller implement these methods:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:animated];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)backgroundClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}


- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    CGFloat searchBarHeight = controller.searchBar.frame.size.height;
    button.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, 0.f, searchBarHeight) ;
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to popToViewController if all you have to do is go back to previous view , just add a back button on navigationcontroller and you can click it to go back :-

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

or if you really want to pop the view use this :-

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;      

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.7];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:<#UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown#> forView:navController.view cache:NO];

    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: i used the second code because i want to go back to the previous view but it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Object at index 0 is root view controller. so it is the first object in the stack. but you can only pop last object. Instead of using

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController: [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

use

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController: [self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject] animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController popToViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```