# searchBarCancelButtonClicked popToRootViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two views, one is the root viewController and the other is a search viewController. When I click cancel on the UISearchBar in the search viewController, I want to segue back to the root viewController. I have this code:

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

But when I click cancel, I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'search contents navigation controller must not change between -setActive:YES and -setActive:NO'
```

What am I doing wrong? The `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` works in other areas of my search view.

Comment: The 2nd answer found here might be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570539/how-to-implement-the-correct-uinavigationbar-back-button-functionality

Comment: I just set up a project as you said and it works perfectly. Maybe you should try `popViewControllerAnimated:` but I don't think that should do the trick.

Comment: @verbumdei that worked! Post it as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before popping the navigation controller, you will need to hide first the search display controller:

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
```

This will hide the search interface without animation.